# How to get screen space you've got for your app or the height of top- and bottom bar in MAUI?

Tags: android, maui

I have a problem calculating the position of some items and if they are visible on the screen in MAUI, using a function like

```
public Point GetScreenCoords(VisualElement view)
{
    var result = new Point(view.X, view.Y);
    while (view.Parent is VisualElement parent)
    {
        result = result.Offset(parent.X, parent.Y);
        view = parent;
    }
    return result;
}
```

More details see there: [MAUI find out if something is on screen does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732747/maui-find-out-if-something-is-on-screen-does-not-work-as-expected)

Now I think I found the reason for the problem. I assume it is the space needed by the small bar at the top of the screen containing the battery indicator and also the bigger bar at the bottom of the screen containing the triangle, circle and square controls. I assume that that space is included in DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height but it is not really available for my app.

I assume if I could respect their heights in the calculation, it would be correct. So my question is:

How can I find out the height of these two bars under MAUI? Or do they posess any Android standard height? What would be this in MAUI device-independent units? Or in screen pixels?

Or alternatively, how can I get the screen height that I really do have for my app? (It is not DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height.)

I am aware of a similar question ([MAUI: how to get the system navigation bar height on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889840/maui-how-to-get-the-system-navigation-bar-height-on-android)) but that one only asks about the bottom bar and has got no accepted answer.

Comment: You really should consider the excellent plugin  [OnScreenSize Markup Extension.](https://github.com/carolzbnbr/OnScreenSizeMarkup.Maui) You then set size break points to ensure you content will scale correctly to fit on all displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I find out the height of these two bars under MAUI?

You can try to use the following code to do that:

```
 var statusid = Platform.CurrentActivity.ApplicationContext.Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
 var statusbarheight = Platform.CurrentActivity.ApplicationContext.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(statusid);
// this is the status bar height
 var navid = Platform.CurrentActivity.ApplicationContext.Resources.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
 var navbarheight = Platform.CurrentActivity.ApplicationContext.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(navid);
// this is the navigation bar height
```

> how can I get the screen height that I really do have for my app? (It
> is not DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height.)

You can use the following code to get the real scren height for your app:

```
var displaymanager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.DisplayService) as Android.Hardware.Display.DisplayManager;
var defaultdisplay = displaymanager.GetDisplay(Android.Views.Display.DefaultDisplay);
var gotheight = Android.App.Application.Context.CreateDisplayContext(defaultdisplay).Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
//this is the real height
```

And the `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height` is the full screen height(contains the two bars).

===================================================

So you can do a judgment :

```
int realheight;
if(gotheight == DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height - statusbarheight -  navbarheight)
    realheight = gotheight;
else if (gotheight == DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height||gotheight == DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height -  navbarheight)
    realheight = gotheight - statusbarheight;
```

Comment: (1/2) Thank you. Your solution seems not to be 100% correct, but very close. I've got an Emulator with H=1920 pix = 640 device-independent units (diu).    I assume diu = pixel divided by DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density, which is 3 here. 
I've measured the real space I have got for my app to be 570 diu.
The values I get from your code are
gotheight = 1776 pix = 592 diu, 
statusbarheight = 72 pix = 24 diu, 
navbarheight = 144 pix = 48 diu. 
So gotheight - statusbarheight = (592-24) diu = 568 diu.

Comment: (2/2) Which is very near to what I am measuring.  Any explanations? 
Did you mean that gotheight - statusbarheight = real space I have got?   I understood you that gotheight should be the real space I have got.

Comment: I tested on the RedMi physical device and the `gotheight = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height - statusbarheight -  navbarheight`. @AndreasW

Comment: And can you show the way to get the 570 diu? @AndreasW

Comment: I get to the 570 diu real available height by creating a Border as top element in the mainpage and then changing its HeightRequest until it visually fits exactly. There might be a mesurement error of plus/minus 2 diu  ...... I see two of your comments are contradicting about gotheight, statusbarheight, navbarheight and DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height!? @Liyun Zhang

Comment: I have tested. On the emulator, the `gotheight = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height -  navbarheight.` So if you want to get the real space can just use the `gotheight - statusbarheight`. And you said mesurement error of plus/minus 2 diu should be causedby the way you get the 570 diu. And the contradiction in my comments is because the different data between the emulator and the physical device. You can debug on physical device to check it. @AndreasW

Comment: So you say it is different for emulator and physical device. Wouldn't this contradict the emulator's purpose? And maybe it's caused by something different? It might be so on some devices and such on some others.......    How can I *in code* find out which one is true? @Liyun Zhang

Comment: Actually, according to the official document about the [DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#heightPixels), the gotheight is what you want. But you can do a judgment to detect if the `gotheight` or the `gotheight - statusbarheight` is you want. @AndreasW

Comment: And did you check it on a physical device? @AndreasW

Comment: I checked on three emulators and two physical devices. On all of them, gotheight - statusbarheight = available height.   Which is different from your results - and from the official documentation!?  Very strange. Still, it seems, there is no real answer on how to find out this height reliably!? @Liyun Zhang

Comment: Please check the code about the judgment in my answer. @AndreasW

Comment: After having accepted your answer, I found a case which is not represented there. I have a case where gotheight == DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height but realheight = gotheight - statusbarheight. May you extend your answer? @Liyun Zhang

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but did that case have the bottom navigation bar? @AndreasW

Comment: It is an Phone-H-DPI emulator with Android 7 API 24 with a screen size of HxW=800x480, density is 1.5. Your code says (in px)  gotheight=800 statusbarheight=36, navbarheight=72.  The really available hight is 764 px. @Liyun Zhang

Comment: But if so, there is no space for the navigation bar. @AndreasW

Comment: There is no navigation bar on the screen. Check it out, create an emulator based on Phone H-DPI 4". @Liyun Zhang